# What does i.reddit.com mean on Reddit?

Tags: reddit

I stumbled upon an i.reddit.com page on Reddit on [this post](https://i.reddit.com/r/gmod/comments/c0th52/im_quitting_garrys_mod_sandbox_because_its/), What does that mean?

Here is what it looks like:
[image: i.reddit.com]

Comment: Welcome. Wouldn't it be correct to quote a substantial piece of the post here, because the link may break in the future, and the question will lose sense?

Comment: @HoRn I would think only a screenshot would help

Comment: Sure. It would also make your post more presentable and easy to read

Comment: @HoRn that posts text is off-topic for the question as only the gui is different

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is shown on i.reddit.com's front page but not on posts.

i.reddit.com is the new mobile site for Reddit.